# How to print MUI X data-grid with image inside renderCell

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm using **MUI X data-grid** to show data using **renderCell**. I want to print my data-grid and see the picture from the first **renderCell**.

```
    const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
        field: 'picture',
        headerName: 'Picture',
        flex: 1,
        headerAlign: 'center',
        align: 'center',        
        renderCell: (params) => <Box component="img"
            sx={{
                height: 56,
                width: 56,
            }}
            src={params.value}
        />,
    },
    {
        field: 'id',
        headerName: 'ID',
        flex: 1,
        headerAlign: 'center',
        align: 'center',
    }
];
```

I don't find any post showing how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

add the following field

```
{
  field: "print",
  headerName: "Print",
  headerAlign: "center",
  align: "center",
  flex: 1,
  renderCell: ({ row }) => {
    return (
      <Box>
        <Tooltip color="success" title="View Calendar Info" arrow>
          <Button onClick={() => handlePrint(row)}>
           <Print/>
          </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </Box>
    );
  },
},
```

Then, define the `handlePrint()` function that receive data from the row and finally print the data you want...if you want the implementation of `handlePrint()` contact me